# De muchos a muchos relacion en eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo un problema cuando quiero hacer una relación de muchos a muchos en laravel. 
Traigo un los 2 id por request y la idea es agregarlos a una tabla intermedia que relaciona estas dos clases.

```
$user->courses()->attach($request['course_id']);
```

Pero si no hay ningún dato anteriormente relacionado me dice que no se puede hacer el attach en "courses" porque es NULL. 
 Y yo lo que necesito es agregarlo sin haber ningún dato relacionado. 
Alguna solución?

Comment: Ya en ese punto del `attach` has guardado el course? Podrías colocar un poco mas de código y también como tienes en tu Model la asociación `courses()`

Comment: Ya lo eh solucionado, el error estaba en que estaba pasando mal el id del curso! Muchas gracias !